# How can I remove the `GET http://localhost:5000/api/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)` showing in the console?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am setting up refresh and access token system for my Vue web application. http://localhost:5000/api/users/profile is the URL of my POST request. I expect an error when someone tries to access and their access token has expired. I use interceptors from Axios in order to generate a brand new access token when such error appears. Everything works fine. However, I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to get rid of the `GET http://localhost:5000/api/users/profile 401 (Unauthorized)` in console. Is there any way to rid of it? Any help would be appreciated.

Getting profile:

```
getProfile: async (context) => {
     context.commit('PROFILE_REQUEST')

     let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/profile')
     context.commit('USER_PROFILE', res.data.user);

     return res;
}
```

Interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((res) => {
        return res;
    }, async (err) => {
        const originalRequest = err.config;

        if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
            originalRequest._retry = true;

            const refreshToken = Cookies.get('jid');

            return axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users/refresh-token', { refreshToken }).then((res) => {
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.data.accessToken}`;
                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.data.accessToken}`;
                originalRequest.baseURL = undefined;
                return axios(originalRequest);
            })
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: First question would be: why get rid of it? Best way to not see an error is to not cause it. You could try to refresh *before* the token expires. Some OAuth2 servers will indicate when the access token will expire.

Comment: you can return a 200 header response from the backend but with error message. so you would know that a particular error has occurred. then alter the interceptors on frontend to match your expected response

Comment: @Karl HTTP response status codes are there for a reason. It's best not to abuse 200

Comment: @Phil i agree, its not ideal to do that. but just an option to satisfy the 'OCD' feeling of getting rid of the console error

Comment: @Evert I think I will try to implement your idea. The 'OCD' feeling just will not let it go.